# Split single long line from text file into multiple lines (CSV)

Tags: regex, csv, perl, split

I have a text file that is a long single line, which I need to split into multiple lines that I can print to a CSV file. I have tried multiple methods, and I'm super close, but my data output is incorrect. I'm stuck on splitting the string into array.

I've tried the code below and, while it is splitting the lines semi-properly, the data is not split into array.

```
open (INPUT, '<', $proxy_file ) or die "Cannot open proxy file\n";
open(OUTPUT, '>', $complete) or die "Cannot create $complete.'\n'";
while(my $line = <INPUT>){
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/,//g;
    $line =~ s/://g;
    my @fields = split /(?<=\.com)/, $line;

    print OUTPUT $_, "\n" for @fields;
```

This is the example data

```
JACOB2345@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, LUKE453@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, WESLEY233@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Bruce2423@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Angel@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Lukder@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU,
```

I want to split it to:

```
FIELD 1             FIELD2
JACOB2345@gmail.com YdjfkoweU
LUKE453@gmail.com YdjfkoweU
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

This code will get you a tab separated CSV:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = 'JACOB2345@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, LUKE453@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, WESLEY233@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Bruce2423@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Angel@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Lukder@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU';

print "Field 1\tField 2\n";

foreach my $rec (split(/,\s*/,$line)) {
    chomp($rec);
    $rec =~ s/:/\t/;

    print $rec,"\n";
}
```

Comment: How would I then print that to a CSV? 1 column for field 1 and another column for field 2?

Comment: Instead of printing it to the terminal, print it to a filehandle...simply wrap your code around this...

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp($line);
  my @rows = split/,\s{1}/, $line;
  foreach my $row (@rows) {
    my ($field_1, $filed_2) = split/:/, $row;
    print "$field_1<=>$filed_2\n";
  }
}



__DATA__
JACOB2345@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, LUKE453@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, WESLEY233@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Bruce2423@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Angel@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU, Lukder@gmail.com:YdjfkoweU,
```